# Change JS function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change this code to take advantage of jQuery?

```
function download(elm) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var param = elm.innerHTML; //$get("filedownload").innerHTML;        
    //iframe.src = "GenerateFile.aspx?filename=386c1a94-fa5a-4cfd-b0ae-40995062f70b&ctype=application/octet-stream&ori=18e73bace0ce42119dbbda2d9fe06402.xls";// + param;
    iframe.src = "GenerateFile.aspx?" + param;

    iframe.style.display = "none";

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
function download(elm) {
  $("<iframe />", { src: "GenerateFile.aspx?" + elm.innerHTML })
    .appendTo("body").hide();
}
```

This is the jQuery 1.4+ [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) syntax, for older versions it would look like this:

```
function download(elm) {
  $("<iframe />").attr("src","GenerateFile.aspx?" + elm.innerHTML)
    .appendTo("body").hide();
}
```

Past the creation [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) appends the element you created to the selector passed in (`"body"`), and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) covers the `display: none;` styling.

Comment: don't forget `iframe.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about $(html, props) syntax before. That would be pretty useful.

Comment: This is why i love jQuery - 7 lines of ugly javascript turned into one chained line of sexiness. :)